# Winrar Delete files after archives cmd

Tags: cmd, automation, winrar

I am trying to get the files to delete after archiving them via cmd. This is possible as shown in the video here [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-FulugaeoI) But i cannot find anything saying how to do this via cmd. theres documentation on it here [Link](https://cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/) And this is code i have so far

```
"cd C:\Users\Jorden\Desktop && "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r -pMyPassword MyArchiveFile *.txt"
```

Comment: WinRAR is installed with a help. It is opened by starting WinRAR and clicking in menu __Help__ on item __Help topics__. The first tab __Contents__ contains the list item __Command line mode__ with a reference to page *Command line syntax* to use as template on writing a WinRAR command line. __Commands__ - *Alphabetic commands list* helps to select appropriate command. And __Switches__ - *Alphabetic switches list* helps to find out which switches to use for a specific task. So there is no need to watch videos or ask other people to build a WinRAR command line. You just have to read the help.

Answer (score 1):

From WinRar documentation (https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwDF.htm)

> Switch -DF - delete files after archiving

Comment: It would have been better to write a comment as I have done explaining where to find appropriate information in help of WinRAR. Even better would be using WinRAR command `m` instead of `a` to move files into an archive.